# Docker Kafka broker not starting no error logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, druid

I am trying to setup druid on my M3 chip laptop.
I am facing some issues in trying to start broker.
I have used this offical docs for refernce.
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/docker
My docker compose file : https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/28.0.1/distribution/docker/docker-compose.yml
Logs which are visible on my container.
`2024-01-12T12:55:31+00:00 startup service broker Setting druid.host=172.18.0.7 in /tmp/conf/druid/cluster/query/broker/runtime.properties`
[image: Error page]
[image: Docker Logs]

1. I tried increasing memory and cpu from docker, which had resolved the issues of lots of people online. Now my containers are not crashing.
2. Tried restarting, deleting container.

docker-compose

```
volumes:
  metadata_data: {}
  middle_var: {}
  historical_var: {}
  broker_var: {}
  coordinator_var: {}
  router_var: {}
  druid_shared: {}


services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - metadata_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=FoolishPassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=druid
      - POSTGRES_DB=druid

  # Need 3.5 or later for container nodes
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.5.10
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1

  coordinator:
    image: apache/druid:28.0.1
    container_name: coordinator
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - coordinator_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command:
      - coordinator
    env_file:
      - environment

  broker:
    image: apache/druid:28.0.1
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - broker_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command:
      - broker
    env_file:
      - environment

  historical:
    image: apache/druid:28.0.1
    container_name: historical
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - historical_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    command:
      - historical
    env_file:
      - environment

  middlemanager:
    image: apache/druid:28.0.1
    container_name: middlemanager
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - middle_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8100-8105:8100-8105"
    command:
      - middleManager
    env_file:
      - environment

  router:
    image: apache/druid:28.0.1
    container_name: router
    volumes:
      - router_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command:
      - router
    env_file:
      - environment
```

Comment: Hey just checking - do you mean that Druid broker is not starting? That's what it looks like rather than your Kafka broker?

Comment: Also you may want to use the learn-druid repo to get Druid running with Docker on your laptop - it includes an ARM image.  https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid